# Occasional crash at NSURLSessionDataTask dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I have a weather app that refreshes asynchronously. While I've never seen it crash myself, I do see about a crash per day in Apple's reports, and not from a specific device. The app does have a good amount of users and it refreshes every few minutes, but I have no idea what kind of percentage send reports to Apple, so don't really know how rare the crash really is. I've tried a few things, like making sure I the Async Downloader class that creates the datatask does not get destroyed etc. There are 2 kinds of reported crashes, the most common is at this code:

```objectivec
-(void)startDownload
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:12];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    if (!session || !request || ![session respondsToSelector:@selector(dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:)])
        return;
    // Stack trace points to line below crashing
    self.dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {...}
    // ...
}
```

The "defensive" `if` is a sanity check as the crash stack trace looks like this:

[image: Stack trace]

That `self.dataTask` is just `@property NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask;`.

Any ideas on what to look into or try in order to avoid this?

I seems quite rare overall so I am wondering if it's a case of the app is getting killed by the system or something like that which causes an unclean termination. Would welcome any suggestion though.

Edit: Couldn't find how to get Xcode to show me more info from the crash dump, but of course I could just open it with a text editor and here is all the info:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  9

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1ca108cb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:202)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1c32243d0 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1ca27dab8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 136 (NSObject.m:140)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1ca11f0e8 ___forwarding___ + 1592 (NSForwarding.m:3578)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1ca185900 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96 (:-1)
5   App                             0x1009667cc -[AsyncDownloader startDownload] + 396 (AsyncDownloader.m:79)
```

Now, going to the thread that triggered this:

```
Thread 9 name:
Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000208743558 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000229411118 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1670)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001d162b178 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022934fbf8 abort_message + 132 (:-1)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022933f444 demangling_terminate_handler() + 348 (:-1)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c3229ea4 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:498)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022934efbc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (:-1)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000022934ef60 std::terminate() + 56 (:-1)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d15caec0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:563)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d15ce330 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 504 (queue.c:306)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d15e1908 _dispatch_source_invoke + 1588 (source.c:961)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d15cde6c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 500 (queue.c:0)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d15dc944 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396 (queue.c:7051)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d15dd158 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164 (queue.c:7119)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022940ada0 _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2631)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022940ab7c start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)


Thread 9 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000229353647   x5: 0x000000016fa2acb0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000002700
    x8: 0xc5115eb4a9cc1e34   x9: 0xc5115eb5c66eae34  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x00000000001ff800  x14: 0x00000000000007fb  x15: 0x000000009002802e
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016fa2b000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000000001e10f  x21: 0x000000016fa2b0e0  x22: 0x0000000000000110  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000016fa2b0e0  x26: 0x0000000000030008  x27: 0x0000000282e3d180
   x28: 0x0000000220904c80   fp: 0x000000016fa2ac20   lr: 0x0000000229411118
    sp: 0x000000016fa2ac00   pc: 0x0000000208743558 cpsr: 0x40001000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: @Rob the `[NSObject doesNorRecognizeSelector]` in the stack trace is the method in the NSobject class that gets invoked to throw the exception when the dynamic method dispatch fails. The OP needs the exception message which will give the details of the object class and the method that was attempted to be invoked.

Comment: @Rob it is a standard session. I will add the rest of the code above for illustration, but session is just an `NSURLSession *`.

Comment: @Paulw11 – Yep, good catch. The stack trace shows `NSObject`. But the exception message says the name of the actual type for which this failed. E.g., [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Q1f.png) I called a `Baz` method on a `Bar` object, where the stack trace reports the error on `NSObject`, but the exception message makes it clear what type of object the failure occurred. E.g., in my example, the `bazMethodNotInBar` was defined in `Baz`, but I forced a call to it from an instance of `Bar` (via an imprudent cast). So, Ecuador, can you show us the actual exception message?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, the exception message would be great, but maybe not available if it's not a DEBUG build? Remember my main issue is I can't reproduce (neither can my beta testers), so only see the crash logs from users in the field. I have now added everything relevant from the crash dump I received from Apple to the question above.

Comment: @Ecuador Could this issue be related to the specific URL (or specific URL scheme) being requested? Perhaps internal to the implementation of `NSURLSession`, it tries to call some method that doesn't actually exist if the wrong kind of URL request is provided. You have an `NSString` named `fileURL`. Where does that come from? What limits are put on its value?

Comment: @HangarRash It's https weather API endpoints. Nothing strange. The user can select weather API and I can see most failures are from the default one, but I get some from the ones users can switch to as well, so it's not URL specific.